# Existence of places other than the hell and heaven

Tags: jannah, hell, eschatology

Recently it was [brought](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10085/why-hell-or-paradise-and-no-in-between?noredirect=1#comment19823_10085) to my knowledge that there are certain hadith which point to the fact that places other then sole hell and heaven exist.

Is it that true?

"Places" here refers to the places in the hereafter.

*References and citations are obviously required here.*

Comment: Well that depends on what you mean by other places? Other places in the *akhira* (hereafter) or other places period?

Comment: I had that in mind but intentionally kept the spectrum a little broad not to restrict the answers discussing places which have connection to place apart from *akhira*. Mentioning hell and heaven implicitly implies akhira though.

Comment: I ask because there is a place between *duniya* and *akhira* called *barzakh* which one enters after death.

Comment: @SystemDown I am aware of that and the fact that it too has levels which will be alloted based on a persons deed. Question updated.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no other place that exists other heaven or hell, so the end will be to either heaven or hell.

> فريق في الجنة وفريق في السعير
>
> A party will be in Paradise and a party in the Blaze
>
> Surat Ashura Ayah Ayah 7

Though before the separating of the people, there will be a people who will be kept in between heaven and hell for as long as Allah wills, neither deserving to go to Jannah nor to Jahannam, they are known as Ahlul A'raaf, then they will enter Jannah.

> وَبَيْنَهُمَا حِجَابٌ ۚ وَعَلَى الْأَعْرَافِ رِجَالٌ يَعْرِفُونَ
> كُلًّا بِسِيمَاهُمْ ۚ وَنَادَوْا أَصْحَابَ الْجَنَّةِ أَن سَلَامٌ
> عَلَيْكُمْ ۚ لَمْ يَدْخُلُوهَا وَهُمْ يَطْمَعُونَ
>
> And between them will be a partition, and on [its] elevations are men
> who recognize all by their mark. And they call out to the companions
> of Paradise, "Peace be upon you." They have not [yet] entered it, but
> they long intensely
>
> Surat Al A'raaf Ayah 46

So I repeat, there is no other place that exists other then heaven or hell.

Comment: none of above verses say there is no other place. please read them again carefully