# What is the concept of araf?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, eschatology

I have studied about "araf". **It is place between heaven and hell** .

I have asked for scholars and there is lot of different views about it .

Some say it place for those who did not get to heaven or hell. and some say it is made for those who did not get the massage of Allah from any prophet. I think it is a mystery in Islam. please share your knowledge with me about araf I want to about it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Existence of places other than the hell and heaven](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10137/existence-of-places-other-than-the-hell-and-heaven). This would give you your answer.

Comment: @Murtaza I don't see how this question is duplicate. In his question he did not mention araf. and he want to know if araf or any other place exist. I want to know want is araf. and who will go there.

Comment: @Murtaza and now i have anothere view about araf that no one will go there. now i have three views. from the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at answer of [that Question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10137/existence-of-places-other-than-the-hell-and-heaven) you will find why I am saying it is duplicate. It gives you one line answer but I think you want detailed answer on it.

---

**Araf** is the **Wall** between Heaven and Hell. Some says it won't be exact **wall** as we see usually but it would be Hill between Heaven and Hell. There would be some people whose good and bad deeds would be equal, they will wait for a time and then they will pass through bridge **Siraat** which is thin like hair and sharp like sword, there they would see Hell at bottom and Heaven in-front.

There are some ayah from **Surah Al'Araf** which are related to araf.

> And between them will be a partition, and on [its] elevations are men who recognize all by their mark. And they call out to the companions of Paradise, "Peace be upon you." They have not [yet] entered it, but they long intensely.
>   *[Surat Al-'A`rāf - 46](http://quran.com/7/46)*
>
> And when their eyes are turned toward the companions of the Fire, they say, "Our Lord, do not place us with the wrongdoing people." [Surat Al-'A`rāf - 47](http://quran.com/7/47)

This should clear your mind about Araf.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araf_(Islam) is this right definition.

Comment: But not enough information about it. Bridge Siraat isn't mentioned in their.